# Persistent storage in kubernetes container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

There is problem , I can't link my pod container with persistent storage

This is config of my pod, where `elastic` is the name of the attached disk (same region, mounted and formatted as should), when I start the pod with this config I have this error:

`Unable to mount volumes for pod elastic.etcd`

I could link my container to any other type of volume either `emptyDir` or `hostDir` and all work fine. But in the case of the mounted disk not. 
And I really can't find some good example about `persitsentDisk` volumes.

```
id: elastic
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1beta1
desiredState:
  manifest:
    version: v1beta1
    id: elastic
    volumes:
      - name: elastic-persistent-storage
        source:
          persistentDisk:
            pdName : elastic
            fsType : ext4
    containers:
      - name: elastic
        image: dockerfile/elasticsearch
        cpu: 1000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: elastic-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /data
        ports:
          - name: elastic
            containerPort: 9200
            hostPort: 9200
labels:
  name: elastic
  role: storage
```

`elastic` is the name of the disk in the same project, same region and attached to master node of claster. Also it is formatted and mounted.

Thanks!

Comment: I've expanded our PD testing and it seems to work correctly. If you continue to encounter problems, please contact us on IRC or comment on that github issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of mounting a PD in the github documentation: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/volumes.md#creating-a-pd

PDs in GCE can only be attached to a single VM (in read/write mode), so if the disk is already attached to your master then it will not be possible to also attach it to the node on which your pod is scheduled. Try detaching the PD from the master and then scheduling the pod.

Comment: First time it worked, but now when I delete and start the same pod again, it freezes in Pending status, I think pods currently, not supposed to work as storage services (maybe later) , it is better now to create common vm instances to contain such kind of services, am I right ?

Comment: This should work.  It's possible that deleting the pod didn't unmount the disk from the original machine.

I will attempt to repro this and see if there is a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/2766 filed

Comment: Oh, you shouldn't attach the disk to the master.  You should have it be un-attached, and the pod will automatically attach it to the correct worker node.